# How to show only searched terms in autcomplete material Ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Reacts Autocomplete material UI and having trouble with one thing.
According to all examples https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ , the list of options is always showed when clicked on input box, But what i want is to display only options related to search term for example in google search box it displays only results related to alphabets entered in box.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexGrow: 1,
  }
}));
const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

export default function Search(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
    console.log(Object.values(props));

  return (    <React.Fragment>          
                <Autocomplete
                  value={value}
                  autoComplete={true}
                  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    setValue(newValue);
                  }}
                  inputValue={inputValue}
                  onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                    setInputValue(newInputValue);
                  }}
                  id="search"
                  options={options}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Search"
                    variant="outlined"
                    helperText="Search By: Product CI, Product Name, Common Name, Application, Competitor Product."
                    />}
                />
                <Box>
                  <img src="/images/searchinfo.jpg" alt="image" style={{width:"100%"}}/>
                </Box>
              </React.Fragment>  
  );
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far at code level post that also

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I have added my code .Please check.

Comment: In that case provide the filtered array to auto-complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to control the Autocomplete open state. Have a look at the following sample:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function Filter() {
  // state for Autocomplete dropdown
  const [autoCompleteOpen, setAutoCompleteOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      open={autoCompleteOpen}
      // This will close the autocomplete on empty text
      // Will collapse on select
      onInputChange={(event, value, reason) => {
        switch(reason) {
          case 'input':
            setAutoCompleteOpen(!!value);
            break;
          case 'reset':
          case 'clear':
            setAutoCompleteOpen(false);
            break;
          default:
            console.log(reason);
        };        
      }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Custom filter"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

Comment: Thanks..  this was very helpful.I am facing one more issue that on select of any option,then the option box dont go away.Please help with this.Thanks again in advance

Comment: Ok, then open appropriate new thread with code sample.

Comment: I am using the same code you provided.So please help.

Comment: I have changed the code to collapse the drop down menu on the select. (onInputChange handler)